# Why in the world does Tkinter break using canvas.create_image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I've got a python GUI app in the workings, which I intend to use on both Windows and Mac. The documentation on Tkinter isn't the greatest, and google-fu has failed me.

In short, I'm doing:

```
c = Canvas(
    master=frame,
    width=settings.WINDOW_SIZE[0],
    height=settings.WINDOW_SIZE[1],
    background=settings.CANVAS_COLOUR
)
file = PhotoImage(file=os.path.join('path', 'to', 'gif'))
c.create_bitmap(position, image=file)
c.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

If I comment out the create_bitmap line, the app draws fine. If I comment it back in, I get the following error:

`_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-image"`

Which is odd. Tkinter is fine, according to the python tests (ie, importing _tkinter, Tkinter, and doing `Tk()`). I've since installed PIL against my windows setup (XP SP3, Python 2.6) imagining that it was doing some of the heavy lifting at a low level. It doesn't seem to be; I still get the aforementioned error.

The full stacktrace, excluding the code I've already pasted, is:

```
File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2153, in create_bitmap
return self._create('bitmap', args, kw)
File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2147, in _create
*(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
```

Anyone able to shed any light?

Comment: Before going any further have you tried your app on a Mac yet ? I once made a Tkinter app on linux that gave me nightmares when I had to port it to Mac : it ran under X (no native aqua support for Tkinter apparently), had tons of bugs that didn't exist on the linux version and once it worked it looked like sh**

Tkinter is poorly documented, the command line oriented API makes it a pain to debug, and in my experience it is not portable. Make yourself a favor and write your app with PyQt4 or wxWindows (I would recommend PyQt4 for the more object oriented API and great documentation)

Comment: Its certainly something I'm considering, at this point. Ultimately, the app I'm writing is a little thing to get used to Tk as a windowing app. I've tinkered with Wx before. I may end up using Qt or Wx for bigger projects.

Comment: addendum: got to test it (in its 'working' form) on my mac yesterday. Works fine. So far, so good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tk has two types of graphics, bitmap and image. Images come in two flavours, bitmap and photo. Bitmaps and Images of type bitmap are not the same thing, which leads to confusion in docs.
PhotoImage creates an image of type photo, and needs an image object in the canvas, so the solution is, as you already concluded, to use create_image.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:
Don't use create_bitmap when you mean to use create_image.

Answer (score 0):

The `create_bitmap()` method does not have an `image` argument; it has a [`bitmap`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/create_bitmap.html) argument instead.

The error you get comes from the fact that in Tkinter, a Tcl interpreter is running embedded in the Python process, and all GUI interaction goes back and forth between Python and Tcl; so, the error you get comes from the fact that Tcl replies "I don't know any -image option in the .create_bitmap call".

In any case, like Jeff said, you probably want the `create_image` method.