# tkinter unknown option "pyimage"

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am running into a similar problem as described here: [Why in the world does Python's Tkinter break using canvas.create_image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824988/why-in-the-world-does-pythons-tkinter-break-using-canvas-create-image)

But I am using `canvas.creat_image` alredy. Please have a look at my code.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="image.gif")

can= tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
can.create_image(400, 400, img)
can.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The error message I get is: `TclError: unknown option "pyimage5"` where the number after pyimage increments by one each time I run it.
The image itself works fine if I run the code below it displays fine...

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="image.gif")

img_label = tk.Label(image=img)
img_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Please also see the system specifcations here.

```
 import IPython
print(IPython.sys_info())
{'commit_hash': '5a894b9',
 'commit_source': 'installation',
 'default_encoding': 'cp1252',
 'ipython_path': 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython',
 'ipython_version': '5.3.0',
 'os_name': 'nt',
 'platform': 'Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0',
 'sys_executable': 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe',
 'sys_platform': 'win32',
 'sys_version': '3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, '
                '13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
can.create_image(400, 400, img)
```

Change it to this:

```
can.create_image(400, 400, image = img)
```

Comment: @mhwh no big deal. It happens. I have done it my self a few times wondering the exact same thing. "WHY WONT IT WORK", 20 min later... Oh.